# Mi duda es porque nodo->valor me da la dirección de memoria y no el valor de mi nodo de la lista

Tags: c++

```
bool Lista::comprobarNumeros(Lista lista, int longitud){
   pNodoLista nodo = lista.primero;
   bool booleano = true; 

   cout << "estamos en comprobarNumeros" << endl;

   for(int i=0; i<longitud; i++){
     cout << "ey";
     if(nodo->valor >= 48 && nodo->valor <=57){
        //si el siguiente elemento de la lista es un operador o )
        if(nodo->siguiente->valor == '+' || nodo->siguiente->valor == '-' || nodo->siguiente->valor == '*' || nodo->siguiente->valor == '/' || nodo->siguiente->valor == ')'){
           nodo = nodo->siguiente;
           cout << "hemos encontrado un numero seguido de un operador o de ) " << endl;
        }
        //por si es una operacion sin parentesis
        else if(nodo->siguiente->valor == 00){
            //nodo = nodo->siguiente;
            cout << "Nada despues del numero" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "El numero no va seguido de operador o parentesis " << endl;
            //nodo = nodo->siguiente;
            booleano = false;
        }
     }
     else{
        //si el elemento actual no es un numero pasa al siguiente elemento
        cout << "Pasamos al siguiente elemento " << endl;
        cout << nodo->valor << endl;
        nodo = nodo->siguiente;
     }
  }
  return booleano;
}

#ifndef LISTA_H
#define LISTA_H
#include "NodoLista.hpp"

class Lista
{
private:
    pNodoLista primero;
    pNodoLista actual;
    friend class Evaluacion; 

public:
    Lista() { primero = actual = NULL;}
    ~Lista();
    void Insertar(int v);
    void Borrar(int v);
    void Mostrar();
    void Siguiente() { if(actual) actual = actual->siguiente; }
    bool ListaVacia() { return primero==NULL;}
    int ValorActual() { return actual->valor;}

    //metodos mios
    bool compararParentesis(Lista lista, int longitud);
    bool comprobarOperador(Lista lista, int longitud);
    bool comprobarNumeros(Lista lista, int longitud);
    //bool comprobarSintaxis(Lista lista, int longitud);


};

#endif // LISTA_H

#ifndef NODOLISTA_H
#define NODOLISTA_H
#include <stdlib.h>

class NodoLista
{
private:     
    int valor;
    NodoLista *siguiente;
    friend class Evaluacion; 
    friend class Lista;

public:
    NodoLista(int v, NodoLista *sig = NULL);
    //~NodoLista();

    int getValor(){
        return valor;
    }

};
typedef NodoLista *pNodoLista;
#endif // NODOLISTA_H
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se define `Lista` y `pNodoLista`?

Comment: private:     
    int valor;
    NodoLista *siguiente;
    friend class Evaluacion; 
    friend class Lista;
    
public:
    NodoLista(int v, NodoLista *sig = NULL);
class Lista
{
private:
    pNodoLista primero;
    pNodoLista actual;